# Formula Expression Error

Tags: formula

Receiving the following error if anyone can see where the error is?

Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 2

```
IF(
    (NOT(ISBLANK(Population__c)) && ((ISPICKVAL(Type__c, "Borough")) || (ISPICKVAL(Type__c, "County")))),
        IF((Population__c / 2) >= 500000, "P10",
        IF((Population__c / 2) >= 250000, "P09",
        IF((Population__c / 2) >= 125000, "P08",
        IF((Population__c / 2) >= 80000, "P07",
        IF((Population__c / 2) >= 40000, "P06",
        IF((Population__c / 2) >= 20000, "P05",
        IF((Population__c / 2) >= 100000, "P04",
        IF((Population__c / 2) >= 5000, "P03",
        IF((Population__c / 2) >= 2000, "P02",
        IF((Population__c / 2) >= 0, "P01",
        NULL)))))))))),


    IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Population__c)) && (NOT(ISPICKVAL(Type__c, "Borough")) || NOT(ISPICKVAL(Type__c, "County"))),
        IF((Population__c) >= 500000, "P10",
        IF((Population__c) >= 250000, "P09",
        IF((Population__c) >= 125000, "P08",
        IF((Population__c) >= 80000, "P07",
        IF((Population__c) >= 40000, "P06",
        IF((Population__c) >= 20000, "P05",
        IF((Population__c) >= 10000, "P04",
        IF((Population__c) >= 5000, "P03",
        IF((Population__c) >= 2000, "P02",
        IF((Population__c) >= 0, "P01", 
        NULL))))))))))),

    IF(ISBLANK(Population__c),
        IF((Total_Budget__c) >= 900000, "B10",
        IF((Total_Budget__c) >= 250000, "B09",
        IF((Total_Budget__c) >= 125000, "B08",
        IF((Total_Budget__c) >= 80000, "B07",
        IF((Total_Budget__c) >= 40000, "B06",
        IF((Total_Budget__c) >= 20000, "B05",
        IF((Total_Budget__c) >= 10000, "B04",
        IF((Total_Budget__c) >= 5000, "B03",
        IF((Total_Budget__c) >= 2000, "B02",
        IF((Total_Budget__c) >= 0, "B01",
        NULL))))))))))),

NULL)
```

Comment: For issues like these, it helps if you take the time to indent each level of nested function. In the process of doing that, the issue may become apparent.

Comment: I agree with indenting. You should also strive to remove all unnecessary parentheses, as they actually hurt readability for most.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Can I ask what you mean by unnecessary parentheses?

Comment: `IF(ISBLANK(Population__c)),` is the prob.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say... crazy calc here. Maybe look for a better way? Perhaps a `Process`?

Anyway, I can see this error: `IF(ISBLANK(Population__c)),`

It should be

```
IF(ISBLANK(Population__c), [all the other nested ifs], NULL)
```

Note, given the extreme nesting, this calculation could have other issues.

Comment: Thanks guys, let me check it out.

Comment: Caspar, I've updated the formula with hopefully better readability and now it's  Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 2